# Is this normal for a gaming laptop?

Tags: laptop

I got a new gaming laptop like 1 month ago.It reaches pretty high temps in some games[like 90 cpu temp on BF4 and Apex Legends].I always close the game after I see such high temperatures because I don't want hardware problems.Is this normal for a gaming laptop?I saw videos on youtube with this laptop and the temps were mostly 86-90 Celsius degrees in games like Apex,Fortnite,The Division.Should I get a cooling pad before I play games that make my laptop's temperatures that high or it's not a problem?My laptop is Asus TUF505DU[Ryzen 7 3750H,GTX 1660Ti and 8gb ram]OS:Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes get a cooling pad if you're going to be doing lots of heavy gaming. It heats up fast and over time can have adverse effects on the hardware.